# Highstock doesn't show all data in serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highstock to show about 10,000 points with two plotted lines that represent a low limit and a high limit. ALl seems to work fine but there are many points that should render outside the limits but they are just shown when zoom in the chart.

this is how my code looks like:

```
                        var chart_DIE_TEMPERATURE =Highcharts.stockChart('container-DIE_TEMPERATURE', {

                            chart: {
                                zoomType: 'x',
                                marginRight: 80
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                    title: {
                                        text: '%'
                                    },
                                plotLines: [
                                     {
                                    color: '#A7DDED',
                                    value: 741.307376468923,
                                    width: '2',
                                    zIndex: 5,
                                    label: {
                                        text: 'Media'
                                    }
                                },
                                    {
                                        value: 750,
                                            color: '#DF6D69',
                                        dashStyle: 'solid',
                                        width: 2,
                                        label: {
                                            text: 'L S E'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        value: 735,
                                        color: '#DF6D69',
                                        dashStyle: 'solid',
                                        width: 2,
                                        zindex:3,
                                        label: {
                                            text: 'L I E'
                                        }
                                    }]
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            rangeSelector: {
                                selected: 1
                            },

                            title: {
                                text: 'GRAFICO DIE_TEMPERATURE'
                            },

                            series: [{
                                name: 'DIE_TEMPERATURE',
                                data: data_DIE_TEMPERATURE,
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                },
                                shadow: false,
                                tooltip: {
                                    valueDecimals: 2
                                }
                            }]
                        });
```

Everything renders well but I want to know why the chart has this behavior.

Here is a live demo. https://jsfiddle.net/lvevano/d09ob5ep/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that some of your points have a value above 750 or below 735. On the initial load the line fits between this range because of the `dataGrouping`. Check the tooltip on your chart - it shows the average points from some range, like `Saturday, Mar 20, 7.30-7.44` - the time range depends on the chart width, tick and points amounts.

More about the `dataGrouping`:

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping

Comment: I checked de API information and change the aproximation value to 'open'. Thanks !!